# Well-ordering principle: why it is needed to state, and then make use?

Tags: natural-numbers, well-orders

I tried to see the well-ordering principle and its necessity.

In many reference, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) I found only statement and applications of it, or its equivalence with mathematical induction.

But, I want to see, what kind of logical problems force us to make it as an axiom?

Can one state some problems, which force us to make the statement of well-ordering on natural numbers, and then use it as an axiom?

Comment: What makes you think that the well-ordering principle is forced by logical problems? It's taken to be an axiom because it allows to do math on top of it.

Comment: For natural numbers, it is a consequence of induction.  You might use it for a proof by contradiction, for example like "suppose statement $p$ is not true for some $n$, then there is a smallest $n$ for which it is not true (using the well ordering principle), but you can show if $p$ is not true for $n$ then it is not true for $n-1$, and given $p$ is true for $n=1$ you have a contradiction"

Comment: Since it is equivalent to induction, you can prove anything using it with induction instead. But often, the well-ordering proof is cleaner to write. For example, any proof that uses a “descent” argument. The well-ordering proof is often by contradiction.